# Google Books API GET Request returns blank screen

Tags: swift, swiftui, codable, google-books-api

Good day, All

So I am learning/practicing Network calls. I came across a video by Paul Hudson where he makes a call to the Itunes API using the same code I am trying to use here. However, I am trying to make a call to the Google Books API. My call (code below) is not working, it (returns a blank screen) I am not sure why. I am of course using variables from the URL I am trying to call/make a request from.

```
import SwiftUI

struct Response: Codable {
    var results: [Result]
}

struct Result: Codable {
    var id: Int
    var etag: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results, id: \.id) { item in
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.etag)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
            // ????
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes") else {
            print("Invalid URL")
            return
        }
        do {
            let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
            if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                results = decodedResponse.results
            }
        } catch {
            print("Invalid data")
        }
    }
}
```

As previously mentioned, this code was tested using the Itunes API and it worked flawlessly. I am not sure what is causing the issue or what can fix it. I will keep searching and practicing on my end.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason your are getting a blank screen, is because your `Response` and `Result` struct do not match the json data you get from
the api. Look carefully at the json data and you will see the difference. Try something like this:

```
struct Response: Codable {
    let items: [Result]  // <--- here
}

struct Result: Codable, Identifiable {  // <--- here
    var id: String      // <--- here
    var etag: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var results = [Result]()
    
    var body: some View {
        List(results) { item in  // <--- here
            VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                Text(item.etag)
            }
        }
        .task {
            await loadData()
        }
    }
    
    func loadData() async {
         guard let url = URL(string: "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=flowers+inauthor:keyes") else {
             print("Invalid URL")
             return
         }
         do {
             let (data, _) = try await URLSession.shared.data(from: url)
             if let decodedResponse = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Response.self, from: data) {
                 results = decodedResponse.items  // <--- here
             }
         } catch {
             print("Invalid data")
         }
     }
    
}
```

Comment: glad it helped. If you use my code with `Result` as `Identifiable` you do not need the id thing. If this answer helped, please mark it as correct.

Comment: THANK  YOU!!!  I overlooked what you pointed out.

Comment: Note, instead of hand making the boring part of the structs, copy and paste the json data into https://quicktype.io/ and all your swift code is generated for you without errors.

Comment: You are totally right about Identifiable. I marked your answer as CORRECT. I deleted my previous comment when I realize that if the Result was conformed to identifiable that would clear the List requirement.

Comment: I just took a look at quicktype.io this will definitely come in handy going forward. Thank you for the heads up.